# Spring Cloud Stream ServiceBus Java for managing dead letter queues

Tags: azureservicebus, spring-cloud-stream, azure-sdk-for-java

are there any options to send/receive from dead letter queue, set dead letter reason and so on using Spring Cloud Stream framework, but not native Azure SDK for Java?

I`ve tried to use some Spring Cloud Stream properties, but hasn`t found any possibilities of dead-letter queue management, but only sending/receiving to/from original ASB queue

Answer (score 1):

- I know you have already tried but as far I know the properties is the only way of reverting the messages to dead letter queue in a case of failure
- Just make sure that the property is set to true.

```
spring.cloud.stream.servicebus.bindings.<binding-name>.consumer.requeue-rejected
```

- This should DLQ the message in an event of failure.

You can refer this [reference guide](https://microsoft.github.io/spring-cloud-azure/current/reference/html/index.html#consumer-properties) on Spring Cloud Stream Binder for Azure Service Bus

Comment: thanks for the answer, I`ve tried this option, but it does not give the opportunity to manage the queue: when requeue-rejected is enabled, then on EACH exception the message is pushed to DLQ without allowing any retries even when set some predefined exceptions (e.g. consumer.retryable-exceptions...)